# how to end a line with with a single linefeed (LF) character ( Unix text file convention ) in Dreamweaver

Tags: php, zend-framework, dreamweaver

I am new to Zend Framework.
In zend framework coding standard,It is recommended to terminate the line with a single linefeed (LF) character (Unix text file convention).

I am using Dreamweaver as IDE to develop applications.

Does Dreamweaver automatically converts "Enter" to single linefeed (LF) character or is there any option to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the help page that has the answer:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7bdda.html

Edit -> Preferences -> Code Format (Line Break Type)